# Joining of strings in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python:

```
A = ['5', 'C', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', 'C', '2.1', '1.0', '2.4', 'C', '5.4', '2.4', '2.6', 'C', '2.3', '1.2', '5.2']
```

I want to join `A` in a a way where output looks like:

```
5\n
C 1.0 2.0 3.0\n
C 2.1 1.0 2.4\n
C 5.4 2.4 2.6\n
C 2.3 1.2 5.2
```

`''.join(A)` joins every string together, `'\n'.join(A)` joins every string starting from new line. Any help for this? Thanks!

Comment: Will each line other than the first always start with a 'C'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can loop through, or just do something like this:

```
' '.join(A).replace(' C', '\nC')
```

The space in the replace string is really important to prevent a leading empty line if the first char is a 'C', and to prevent trailing whitespace in other places. (Thanks @aruisdante)

Comment: Probably the easiest/most efficient without adding significant complexity. You should note in your answer that the space in your replace string is really important to prevent a leading empty line if the first char is a ``'C'`` and trailing whitespace in other places.

Comment: This is a great answer if the data is not more complex than the posted example.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan P, aruisdante, g.d.d.c: .replace() works for my problem.

Comment: @Ryan P, what if I want to save output as a list, where each line in the output is a list of list.

Comment: Add `.split('\n')`, or else just loop through and build the lists (like @CoDEmanX's answer, without the `join`s).

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably employ some itertools functionality.

```
from itertools import izip

def chunks(iterable, num=2):
  it = iter(iterable)
  return izip(*[it] * num)

print '\n'.join([A[0]] + [' '.join(c) for c in chunks(A[1:], 4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any imports:

```
A = ['5', 'C', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', 'C', '2.1', '1.0', '2.4', 'C', '5.4', '2.4', '2.6', 'C', '2.3', '1.2', '5.2']

B = []

j = 0
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    if a == 'C':
        B.append(A[j:i])
        j = i
B.append(A[j:])

print(("\n".join(" ".join(b) for b in B)))
```